# Prove $D_{2n}/\langle r^k\rangle$ is isomorphic to $D_{2k}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, dihedral-groups, quotient-group

Let $D_{2n} =\langle r,s\ |\quad r^n = s^2 = 1, rs = sr^{-1}\rangle$ be the usual presentation of the dihedral group of order $2n$ and let $k$ be a positive integer dividing $n$.

> Prove that $D_{2n}/\langle r^k\rangle$ is isomorphic to $D_{2k}$,
> where $\langle r^k\rangle$ is a normal subgroup of $D_{2n}$.

My attempt: Suppose $f: D_{2n}/\langle r^k\rangle\  \longrightarrow\ D_{2k}$ is a homomorphism of groups. Then recall the first isomorphism theorem, if $f: G \rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism of groups, then $\ker f$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $G/\ker f$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{im}f$.

Then I need to show $\ker f =\langle r^k\rangle$ and $\operatorname{im}f= D_{2k}$. So we can conclude by the first isomorphism theorem that $D_{2n}/\langle r^k\rangle$ is isomorphic to $D_{2k}$..
Can someone please help me? I am stuck.Thank you

Comment: Your logic is faulty. You should not **suppose** that $f : D_{2n} / \langle r^k \rangle \to D_{2k}$ is a homomorphism of groups. You should instead **write down a formula** for a homomorphism of groups $f : D_{2n} / \langle r^k \rangle \to D_{2k}$, and then prove that your formula defines an isomorphism.

Comment: k is a positive integer dividing n. So it is smaller than n. It is not false.

Answer (score 1):

You mention all the right ingredients, but you don't seem to put them together in a coherent way. Try the following approach:

1. Show that for any positive integer $k$ dividing $n$ the map defined by
   $$\varphi_k:\ D_{2n}\ \longrightarrow\ D_{2k}:\ \begin{array}{c}s\ \longmapsto\ s'\\ r\ \longmapsto\ r'\end{array},$$
   is a group homomorphism, where
   \begin{eqnarray*}
   D_{2n}&=&\langle r,s\ \mid\quad r^n=s^2=1,\ rs=sr^{-1}\rangle\\
   D_{2k}&=&\langle r',s'\ \mid\quad r'^k=s'^2=1,\ r's'=s'r'^{-1}\rangle
   \end{eqnarray*}
2. Show that $\varphi_k$ is surjective.
3. Show that $\ker\varphi_k=\langle r^k\rangle$.
4. Apply the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: would the map still work even though it does not look like the map is going from a quotient to D_{2k}? in order to apply the first isomorphism theorem?

Comment: Do you know what the [first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem) says?

Comment: yes.  I wrote it above, but I was confused about how your map is defined. My professor said I had to match what the first isomorphism theorem said to the map.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by your second sentence.

Comment: @user220932 That is step 4. Use steps 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: @Servaes Can you provide details about how to show that the $\varphi$ you've defined is a homomorphism? I'm having trouble showing $\varphi(ab) = \varphi(a) \varphi(b)$, even writing elements in terms of the generators $r$ and $s$.

Comment: @Junglemath The relations defining $D_{2n}$ imply that for every $x\in D_{2n}$ there exist integers $a$ and $b$ with $0\leq a<n$ and $0\leq b<2$ such that $x=r^as^b$. From here it should not be hard to verify that $\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$, using the fact that $rs=sr^{-1}$.