# Complete preimage and isomorphism type

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G = D_{16}$ be the dihedral group of order $16$ generated by a rotation  $r$ and a symmetry $s$. Let $\bar{G} = G/<r^4>$ be a quotient group. Let $\bar{H} = <\bar{s},\bar{r^2}>$

I am asked "describe the isomorphism type of the complete preimage of $\bar{H}$ in $G$"

Can you explain what is being asked for here?
What is a *complete* preimage?
Is asking the isomorphism *type* just asking what group a group is isomorphic to?

This is part of Dummit and Foote exercise 3.1.17e

Comment: If $f$ is the surjective homomorphism $f\colon G\rightarrow \overline{G}$, then the preimage is $H=f^{-1}(\overline{H})$, complete or not complete (I don't know). Then this group $H$ is isomorphic to what? You can use [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1439746/prove-d-2n-rk-is-isomorphic-to-d-2k?rq=1).

Comment: Let $A$ and $B$ be sets and $f: A \rightarrow B$ then for $S \subseteq B$ a preimage of $S$ (with respect to $f$)  is a subset  $T \subseteq A$ such that $f(T) \subseteq S$. The complete preimage is the maximal set that satisfies the prperty of being a preimage. For isomorphism type just read it as structure description like "dihedral group of order...." or "cyclic group of order ...."

Comment: Bogaerts Marc, so under this definition, the empty set will be a preimage (just not necessarily complete).  My previous understanding of preimage was Dietrich Bird's version. This makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The elements of G are $\{1,r, \ldots, r^7, s, sr, \ldots,sr^7  \}$, which of them are projected into $\bar{H}$?

Answer (score 0):

From page 83 of chapter 3:quotient groups and homomorphisms:
"The complete preimage of a subgroup of $G/N$ is a subgroup of G which contains the subgroup N since these are the elements which map to the identity $ \bar{1} \in \bar{H} $ ".
Hope to help you.